# Is this possible with Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database that looks like the following

```
{
   00001: {
     "destination": "A",
     "name": "John Doe",
     "status" : "1",
     "taken"  : "0"
   },
   00002: {
     "destination": "A",
     "name": "Doe John",
     "status" : "1",
     "taken"  : "0"
   },
   00003: {
     "destination": "Undefined",
     "name": "Dell MacApple",
     "status" : "0",
     "taken"  : "0"
   },
   00004: {
     "destination": "B",
     "name": "John Macintosh",
     "status" : "1",
     "taken"  : "1"
   }
}
```

Would it be possible for me to create a complex query that only prints children that meet very specific criteria?

For example, If I wanted only users who's `"status" is "1"` `"taken" is "0"` `"destination" is "A"`, would I then be able to print the `name`?

Would I be able to get output like `John Doe and Doe John meet these requirements`?

Comment: this is a common topic here and the question I linked pretty much cover the whole subject. After reading take your try with swift/objective-c ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data)) and let us know if you have any other specific doubt.

Comment: Thank you very much